# How to extract first element from a JSON structure in KQL?

Tags: kql

I have a JSON data structure like this stored in a column:

```
{
  "Attributes": "[\"AnAttribute\"]",
  "WorkItems": "[\"674746\"]",
  "AuthorAliases": "[\"AnAlias\"]"
}
```

I want to extract the first element from one of the arrays. I try the below, but it doesn't work. What am I misunderstanding here?

**Query**

```
let t = datatable (data:string) [
   @'{"Attributes": "[\"AnAttribute\"]","WorkItems": "[\"674746\"]","AuthorAliases": "[\"AnAlias\"]"}'
];
t
| extend asDyn = todynamic(data)
| extend WorkItems = asDyn["WorkItems"]
| extend WorkItem = WorkItems[0]
```

**Result**

| data | asDyn | WorkItems | WorkItem |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| {"Attributes": "["AnAttribute"]","WorkItems": "["674746"]","AuthorAliases": "["AnAlias"]"} | {"Attributes": "["AnAttribute"]", "WorkItems": "["674746"]", "AuthorAliases": "["AnAlias"]"} | ["674746"] |  |

Answer (score 0):

```
let t = datatable (data:string) [
   @'{"Attributes": "[\"AnAttribute\"]","WorkItems": "[\"674746\"]","AuthorAliases": "[\"AnAlias\"]"}'
];
t
| extend asDyn = parse_json(data)
| extend WorkItems = parse_json(tostring(asDyn["WorkItems"]))
| extend WorkItem = WorkItems[0]
```

| data | asDyn | WorkItems | WorkItem |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| {"Attributes": "["AnAttribute"]","WorkItems": "["674746"]","AuthorAliases": "["AnAlias"]"} | {"Attributes":"["AnAttribute"]","WorkItems":"["674746"]","AuthorAliases":"["AnAlias"]"} | ["674746"] | 674746 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA8tJLVEoUbBVSEksAcKknFQFDRDTqrikKDMvXVMhmpdLQUHBQb1aybEEKJRUWpJarGSloBQdo%20SYBxeKUYpV0lEKzy/K9ixJzYUpMDM3MTcxg8g5lpZk5Bc55mQmFiMbAOKDFNSq83LFWvNylfBy1SikVpSk5qUoJBa7VOYBnVaQWFScGp9VnJ8HdpomkhK4jajKSvIhztcAGxGN5LBYTWzagbrhSqINYgHbscDAFAEAAA==)